# Float formatting C++

Tags: c++, precision

Got the following code:

```
float f;
std::cin >> f;
std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::right << std::setprecision(3) << f << "\n";
```

If I put on the standard input the number 100, it will display 100 without precision (padding & alignment work).
I would like to get the result: 100.000 instead...
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `std::fixed` like so:

```
float f;
std::cin >> f;
std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::right << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << f << "\n";
```

Comment: Also `setw` makes no sense because it's too small.